# How do I install my printer to ubuntu?

Tags: printing

Hello Ubuntu community I have been having trouble with school because I haven't been able to print documents from Ubuntu(mostly because I don't know how to :( sad face) I was wondering if any of you nice people could help me so I can turn in my work and not get bad grades.

The printer I have:
HP Officejet Pro 8600

Thank you so much if you helped

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search and I found this: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_pro_8600.html

Looks like the latest drivers are for Ubuntu 15.10, as of 1/12/2016.

Click on the "Download HPLIP" button near the top of the page, and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this very same printer with Ubuntu, but only for Wi-Fi printing.  I do not remember downloading any additional drivers (I think they came with Ubuntu 15.10).

Try going to System Settings -> Printers.

Answer (score 0):

You need `hplip`, which can be downloaded and installed easily. It provides support for printing, faxing, and scanning (including duplex scanning and printing) for HP all-in-one printers. I have an 8620 myself.

Install HPLIP in Ubuntu/Linux Mint:

1. download HPLIP .run installer from:  [Download HPLIP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/)
2. Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run command to give executable permission to the installer:

   `cd ~/Downloads/ && chmod +x hplip-*.run`
3. Finally start the installer and follow the terminal prompts:

   `cd ~/Downloads/ && ./hplip-*.run`

*Courtesy of [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/04/hplip-support-ubuntu-1504-linuxmint-17-1/).*